# E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview

** I want to know what mistake  i did so occure its error please tell meWhat solution of this error  can anyone tell me how to fix this problem :E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout,i couldn't solve yet please tell me how i fix this error...........................................................................................................................................**

search.xml

```
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar_layout_search"
        android:visibility="gone">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

search.kt

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false)

        recyclerView=view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_search)
        recyclerView?.setHasFixedSize(true)
        recyclerView?.layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(context)
        mUser=ArrayList()
        userAdapter=context?.let{ UserAdapter(it,mUser as 
       ArrayList<User>,true) }
        recyclerView?.adapter=userAdapter
        view.search_edit_text.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher{


            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }
```

Comment: The context might be null

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false" to your LinearLayoutManager initialization as follow
**LinearLayoutManager(context, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)**
also make sure your adapter is initialized properly (try adding a Log after your useAdapter initialization)

Comment: can you share your xml?

Answer (score 0):

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_hashtags"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:listitem="@layout/item_trending"/
```

1. Check the context which you are using. If its null the adapter might not get attached and the above error might occur
2. app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" This line can help you get rid of the above error.